# Passing HTML using JSON

Tags: html, json, encoding

I'm passing Data using JSON to iPhone and iPad.
One Field of Data is HTML.

The problem is the encoding.

Here's what I get back:

```
> "GadgetHTML": "<strong>Hello</strong>
> from Catworld<br />\n<img alt=\"\"
> src=\"http://www.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/ifunny/128/dog-icon.png\"
> />",
```

The \ are killing me.
The \n does not help.

Any good way to do this?

Any JSON to HTML Cleaning Functions?
Encoding?

(There must be something better than manually removing )

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is HTML, it is just JSON encoded. Use a standard JSON parser and the string you get back will have the escape characters handled for you…

… or are you trying to write your own JSON parser? (Probably not a good idea, but if you really want to reinvent the wheel then the spec is at http://json.org (and the ECMA-262 specification would probably help you for the grammar)).

Comment: Hi David, Thanks.
We are in fact already using the Google JSON Framework...So I thought It should handle the escaping automatically. Seems not the case. 
Is there some framework Flag I am missing? 

Some specific 'CleanJSON' call? 
thx

Answer (score 0):

The service that sends the JSON Block should escape all back slashes with another backslash.

Comment: That would change `alt\"` into `alt=\\"` so the data would include a `\` character, then there would be a `"` character which (as it wouldn't be escaped any longer) would terminate the string, so the next character would invalidate the JSON.

Comment: Yeah - escaping needed for the wire. Just not after landing on client. But thanks