# JSON data html parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

why JSON doesn't work with html text (var text_html = '`<p></p><t></t>`'; ) but this will be work correct (var text_html = 'example';)

doesn't work

```
var text_html = JSON.parse('<p></p><t></t>');
```

Problem:

```
    function Save() {
        var text_html = '<p></p><t></t>'; 
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                My_Text: text_html
            },
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                }

            }
        });
    }
</script>

public JsonResult DodajTematSave(string My_Text)
        {

            return Json(new { Success = true});
        }
```

also this doesn`t work

```
var dom_string = '<div>xxx<div>yyy</div></div>';
    var text_html = dom_string.innerText();
```

also this doesn`t work

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Save() {
        var Temat_controll = $('#Temat').val();

        var Streszczenie_controll = $.parseJSON('<p></p><t></t>'); 

        var PelnyOpis_controll = $('#PelnyOpis').text();

         $.ajaxSetup({
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json"
         });

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("DodajTematSave", "StronaGlowna")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                Temat: Temat_controll,
                Streszczenie: Streszczenie_controll,
                PelnyOpis: PelnyOpis_controll
            },
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    alert('success');
                }

            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047311/passing-html-using-json

Comment: is your error about data format when it is posted or does the post fail to reach your action method?

Comment: @Dave A I have got error when this text is going to method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var Streszczenie_controll = $.parseJSON('<p></p><t></t>');
```

and use ajaxSetup to instruct JQuery how to handle the data type

```
        $.ajaxSetup({
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

Comment: is it possible convert this using JQuery?

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper, that IS JQuery. Interesting it didn't work. same error?

Comment: all the time this same problem. I tried convert also using JQuery but doesn`t help look into my edited post.

Comment: When I write this-> var dom_string = "<div>xxx<div>yyy</div></div>"; alert("Variable y value is " + typeof (dom_string)); I get information y is String but doesn`t work

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper, I'm surprised and maybe reaching, but lets try using ajaxSetup. check my revised answer.

Comment: doesn`t work but I added example (in my post) how I added this code to my code

Answer (score 2):

Because those are escaping characters in JSON.  You will have to parse html in a way to make it JSON friendly if you wanted it passed through JSON.

Answer (score 2):

For this people who have problem with this I can show another way to fix this problem but very ugly [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602665/replace-all-tags/15602705?noredirect=1#15602705)