# replace all tags

Tags: jquery

I would like to **replace all** tags like this but not only first similar tag.

Code:

```
var s = "<p>Hello World!</p><p>By Mars</p>";
s = s.replace('<', '!!!111!!!').replace('</', '!!!222!!!').replace('>', '!!!333!!!');
alert(s);
```

Return Value:

```
!!!111!!!p!!!333!!!Hello World!!!!222!!!p><p>By Mars</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace multiple occurances you use a regular expression as the first parameter, so that you can specify the `g` global flag:

```
s = s.replace(/<\//g, '!!!222!!!').replace(/</g, '!!!111!!!').replace(/>/g, '!!!333!!!');
```

Note that you have to replace `</` before `<`, otherwise there will never be any `</`.